# "whichever is (the) less", vs "whichever is (the) lesser"

Tags: phrases

I would like to have advice on the differences between "whichever is (the) less" and "whichever is (the) lesser".  Are they both grammatically correct?  If yes, under what circumstances should they be used, especially when being placed at the end of a sentence?  I found both in different legislations and government documents.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**1) Whichever is less**
   Among very few things (two preferably)

**2) Whichever is lesser**
   Used for comparing among two or more number of things

**3) Whichever is the least**
   The thing which is less than all of the other things

Yes, they all may sound like they have the same meaning, and it's mostly up to you whatever sense you want to deliver to the reader.